# Angular JS Datatables row click event add dynamic AngularUI Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-datatables, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I wanted to do a browser like tabs but the event will be triggered inside a angular datatables (im using this one - [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/rowClickEvent)). I have already setup the controller to listen on click per row to add a dynamic tab. But sadly, it does not add the tab. I logged the `$scope.tabs` array and found out that the tab was added but not on the `<uib-tabset>`. Please refer to the screenshot below;

[image: sample]

Above screenshot shows the datatable, when i click the highlighted box (red) it was supposed to add a tab after "Dyanamic Title 1" tab and set it as active (or currently selected tab). How do i do this everytime i click a row it will add a dynamic tab?

Here is my controller for angularJS

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',
                           'API_URL',
                           'DTOptionsBuilder',
                           'DTColumnBuilder',
                           '$resource',
    function($scope, API_URL, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $resource){
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
        ];

        $scope.model = {

        };

        var vm = $scope;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(API_URL+'employee')
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withBootstrap()
            .withOption('rowCallback', function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                $('td', nRow).unbind('click');
                $('td', nRow).bind('click', function() {
                    $scope.tabs.push({
                        title: aData.empid,
                        content: 'Testing Content'
                    });
                });
            });

        vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('empid').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fname').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lname').withTitle('Last name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('position').withTitle('Position'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email'),
        ];
}]);
```

Here is my html

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="[[ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') ]]" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Angular DataTables -->
        <link href="[[ asset('/css/angular/angular-datatables.min.css') ]]" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="[[ asset('/css/angular/datatables.bootstrap.min.css') ]]" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="medrec">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- header -->
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
                        <uib-tabset active="active">
                            <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">
                                <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" 
                                       dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover" 
                                       width="100%">
                                </table>
                            </uib-tab>
                            <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
                                {{tab.content}}
                            </uib-tab>
                        </uib-tabset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @include('templates.footer')
        <!-- jQuery  -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/js/jquery.2.2.3.min.js') ]]"></script>

        <!-- jQuery DataTables -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') ]]"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Library -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-datatables.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-animate.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-route.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-touch.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-resource.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/lib/angular.ui-bootstrap.min.js') ]]"></script>


        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') ]]"></script>
        <script src="[[ asset('/js/angular-datatables.bootstrap.min.js') ]]"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Modules -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/app.js') ]]"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Config -->
        <!-- script src="[[ asset('/app/config/route.js') ]]"></script -->

        <!-- AngularJS Directives -->
        <!-- script src="[[ asset('/app/controller/directive.js') ]]"></script -->

        <!-- AngularJS Controllers -->
        <script src="[[ asset('/app/controller/main-controller.js') ]]"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating a `$scope` variable from within a jQuery callback. I believe you can force an update of the `<uib-tab>`'s by using `$apply` :

```
$scope.tabs.push({
  title: aData.empid,
  content: 'Testing Content'
});
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: ohh i see your right.. didn't think about that having been a jQuery callback.. been so focused on the angular aspect of it.. by the way.. how do you autoselect the newly added tab? am using active set to current tab index but it wont do

Comment: @lemoncodes, have you considered adding `active: true` to the literal you are pushing to `tabs`? `$scope.tabs.push({  title: aData.empid,  content: 'Testing Content', active: true });` This seems to be the way, you have `active="tab.active"`. I am not so familiar with `uib-tab`'s, using angularstrap myself.

Comment: yes, tried using it but it wont select the newly added tab.. yes that what i was thinking also, but it seems it does not follow.. i've been reading the angular-ui bootstrap docu but i really dont get it as to how to select a tab.. since on the document, when you suelect a tab using a button, ng-click part will just have a value of active = <tab index>

Comment: by the way man.. i think the added question is a bit out of topic, i created a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090687/auto-select-angularui-added-dyanmic-tab.. for everybody's information